# Unable to use Profile report of Pandas Profiling

Tags: python, pandas, attr, pandas-profiling

The problem is that I am getting error:

```
module 'attr' has no attribute 's'
```

when using:

```
pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(df)
```

[image]

I don't understand the connection of error.

The  error is very large but you can see a part here how it reached module attr.

[image]

I printed head of required columns.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your dataframe please?

Comment: It would be a lot easier for everyone if you would just show us the general structure your data and the code you're running before getting this error. I'm afraid `pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(df)` is not enough to understand the problem.

Comment: Its really a huge datframe with about 40 columns , I am not sure how can I post it. But I was able to run this before but after the pc was flashed , I am getting this error

Comment: df.head() and df.columns outputs should be sufficient to start with.

Comment: I added pic, Hope I did it in required way. I believe this is something to do with software versions or so. Because the same data has given me output before